# When filtering with data in civicrm/contact/view/case&reset=1 I get an error and no filtering

Tags: civicase, ajax, date-preferences

I have a problem in civicrm/contact/view/case&reset=1 when I use the date filter.

I have an Italian localization with date format set to dd/mm/yyyy.

I choose a date in the calendar and then I get the folowing error on screen:

> DataTables warning: table id=case_id_2566 - Invalid JSON response. For
>   more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/1

And if I look into DevTools I have this return from the site:

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
>   moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
>   with more details about what action you were performing when this
>   occurred. One of parameters (value: 09/04/2018) is not of the type
>   Date

Which is not the dateformat set in localization (dd/mm/yyyy) but probably the default (mm/dd/yyyy)

Comment: I get the same error if I do it on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org even if I do not change the dateformat to dd/mm/yyyy and leave it to the US default.

Comment: yep, might be bug as `09/04/2018` is a correct value for both format mentioned above ;-)